# How to get count of data based on the pivot table laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, count

I have three tables,

```
     User                   cities             user_cities

id name    title           id   name        user_id   city_id
1   aaa   designer         1   cityA          2         1
2   bbb   developer        2   cityB          2         3
3   ccc   designer         3   cityC          1         2
4   ddd   designer                            3         3
5   rrr   developer                           3         2
                                              4         2
                                              4         3
```

Now i am going to filter user by their `title=designer`. Then the filter data will be,

```
     user

id name    title          
1   aaa   designer                
3   ccc   designer         
4   ddd   designer
```

Along with this data i have to get the count of cities like this,

```
data: {
   0: {
      name:cityB,
      id:2,
      count:3
    },
    1: {
      name:cityC,
      id:3,
      count:2
    }
}
```

How can i get this with laravel eloquent?

Comment: You Use laravel 5.8 then use withCount or Declare Your Model $withCount varible
refer this doc laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: Did you solved the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$users = App\User::where('title', 'designer')->get();
```

and use

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->cities->count(); // collection count
}
```

But the better way will be [Counting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```
$users = App\User::withCount('cities')->where('title', 'designer')->get();
```

and then

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->cities_count; // relationship count
}
```